# Explain the mechanism of the following reaction, which involves a 1,2-alkyl migration with double inversion of configuration

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, hydrolysis, rearrangements

I came across the following reaction, whose mechanism is said to involve a 1,2-alkyl migration with a double inversion in configuration. The reagents used were nitrous acid (generated in situ) followed by acidic hydrolysis.

[image]

I got a hint that the first step involves the reaction of nitrous acid with the NH group. But, I cannot understand how the reaction works. Could anyone explain the mechanism?

Comment: Are these structures correct? As drawn the product has gained a methyl group at the top which has no apparent source.

Comment: There was a mistake in the structure I drew. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's original structure is missing a quaternary methyl group (since amended) because the structure **1** is derived from [α-santonin<sup>[1]</sup>](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00398a002) with hydroxylamine. Nitrosation of **1** affords **2** that undergoes acid-catalyzed fragmentation to give secondary carbocation **3**. A suprafacial 1,2-methyl shift produces tertiary cation **4**. Two fates of carbocation **4** may be considered. One is to form intermediate **7** that loses nitrous oxide to give epoxide **6**. Alternatively, carbocation **4** loses nitrous oxide forming alcohol **5**, which undergoes ring closure to form epoxide **6**. These mechanistic considerations are not discussed in the reference.

[image]

1. J. T. Edwards and M. J. Davis, [*J. Org. Chem.*, **1978**, *43*, 536](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00398a002). https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00398a002